# confused by this for loop syntax

Tags: java, language-agnostic

Can you please explain how this for loop work?

```
   for (int i = 0, ii = deck.size(); i != ii;) {

      int x = i % NUMBER_OF_CARDS;
      int y = i / NUMBER_OF_CARDS;

      Card d = deck.get(i++);

      d.setFace(true);                            // face up
      d.displayCard(40 + x * 90, y * 140 + 10);   // draw them
      println(d.getRank());                       // println
      text("Value:" + d.getRank() + " of " + d.getSuit(), 40+x * 90, y * 140 + 120);
    }
```

Comment: Downvoting this is wrong-headed, IMO.  It's a question seeking understanding, asked in a concrete way

Comment: I didn't downvote but it's still not a good question. *What part* of the loop doesn't the OP understand? (I'm guessing it's the `i != ii`)  It's generous that you decided to answer, but the question itself in this form shouldn't be encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for loops have three sections, separated by ;

1. Initialization;
2. Termination condition;
3. Iteration     (something to do every time through the loop)

All three parts are optional.  You could write a loop like  this `for(;;) {}` and it would go on forever.  Or this: `for(;;) { break; }` and it would terminate immediately. Or like this:

```
int i = 0;  
for(;;) {
  if (++i>=4) { break; } 
}
```

and it will terminate after four iterations, via `break`.

The loop from your question is missing the iteration section.  (But loop variables are being updated in the loop body itself, such as `i++`).

The only other special feature is that the loop is initializing two variables in the first section, `i` and `ii`.  They are separated by a comma operator, which causes the comma separated expressions to be independently evaluated in sequence.

Answer (score 5):

The loop,

```
for (int i = 0, ii = deck.size(); i != ii;) {
    ...
    Card d = deck.get(i++);
    ...
}
```

is almost equivalent to

```
for (int i =0; i < deck.size(); i++) {
    ...
    Card d = deck.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two main line of this loop is:

```
for (int i = 0, ii = deck.size(); i != ii;) {
      Card d = deck.get(i++);
}
```

equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0, ii = deck.size(); i != ii;) {
      Card d = deck.get(i);
      i++; // or i = i + 1
}
```

But very different if:

```
Card d = deck.get(++i);
// mean:
// i++; // increase i before take from deck
//card d = deck.get(i);
```

base on this, we move `i++` part to for loop instead increase it in function body. So we can change to "normal loop" is:

```
for (int i =0; i < deck.size(); i++) {
    Card d = deck.get(i);
}
```

@: I still don't know why this code writes as in your example. :)

Answer (score 1):

It loops until the deck size is reached. the loop variable i is incremented later in the 3rd line. A bit strange doing it that way. Bad readability.